# Creating an R/Shiny Multi-layer Pictogram

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, graph, shiny

I'm working on creating a pictogram of a person's risk. I've trying to display it graphically so it clearly shows the added risk for different factors.

This is what my graph looks like currently:

[image]
I'd like to be able fill in with red hearts just the risk for a certain factor and fill in the rest of the row with green hearts. So for example the HxCHF would either fill from 0 to ~14.1 and then from 14.1 to 18.5 would be filled with green (ideally it would scale all the way to 100 but I've found the graphics don't scale well past ~20).

I think the problem is becuase I clip the final red heart in a row and make the rest of that heart transparent I get those gaps. Is there anyway to create a dummy dataFrame of green hearts that runs to the max risk and then overlay the red risk hearts on top? Or even just fill part of the graph with  red hearts, such as from 14-16 with red hearts and then 0-14 and 16-18 with green, for example?

I'm using these methods to build the graph:

```
library(png)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

fill_images <- function() {
l <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(newDF))
{
  for (j in 1:dfMaster[1,'MajorComplications']) #From another DF with the max risk overall
  {
    if(j <= ceiling(newDF$units[i]))
      img <- readPNG("www/Heart_symbol_c00.png")
    else
      img <- readPNG("www/green-heart-md.png")
    g <- rasterGrob(img, interpolate=TRUE)
    l <- c(l, annotation_custom(g, xmin = i-1/2, xmax = i+1/2, ymin = j-1, ymax = j))
  }
}
})
l
}

clip_images <- function(restore_grid = TRUE) {
l <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(newDF)) {
  l <- c(l, geom_rect(xmin = i-1/2,
                    xmax = i+1/2,
                    ymin = newDF$units[i],
                    ymax = ceiling(newDF$units[i]),
                    colour = "white",
                    fill = "white"))
  if (restore_grid && ceiling(newDF$units[i]) %in% major_grid)
   l <- c(l, geom_segment(x = i-1,
                         xend = i+1,
                         y = ceiling(newDF$units[i]),
                         yend = ceiling(newDF$units[i]),
                         colour = grid_col,
                         size = grid_size))
}
l
} 

grid_col <- "grey50"
grid_size <- 0.6
major_grid <- 0:10 * 2
p <- ggplot(newDF, aes(what, units)) +
  fill_images() +
  clip_images() +
  geom_bar(fill=NA, colour="transparent", size=1.2, alpha=0.5, stat="identity") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 20, 2)) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x  = element_blank(), axis.title.y  = element_blank(),
     panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour = grid_col, size = grid_size),
     panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = NA))
p
```

---

As a smaller aside question, when I reorder the dataFrame to put the current risk at the top and order it in descending risk order via: `newDF < arrange(newDF,units)` the row labels don't reorder. Any idea why that is?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: on the aside, use `reorder` instead of `arrange` as it's the order of the factor levels that matters, not the order of the dataframe

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example. I'm trying something like this and getting weird errors. `newDF <- reorder(newDF, X=as.numeric(newDF$units), FUN=length)`

Comment: `reorder(newDF$units, X= newDF$units, FUN = length)`

Comment: not sure what `newDF` looks like, but I think the above is about right

Comment: This is what the DF looks like: `units         what
28.34507 Current Risk
21.00918        HxCHF ...` But when I run that I get errors and weird console print outs